# Regression equation using percentage values in R : Request your help for a beginner

Tags: percentage

Can percentage values be independant variables? Can I use then as it is, or do I need to take log. And also if I have to consider interaction effects when independent variables are percentages, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 0.01 actually equals to 1% and so on.

However you need to make sure that all your data and features are on the same scale so your model won`t be biased towards the features with higher values in Error calculations.

you can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/greyatom/why-how-and-when-to-scale-your-features-4b30ab09db5e)